# Add a new integer before a target integer?

Tags: java, linked-list

I am currently working on a code that allows me to add an element to a linked list before a specified target integer, this is what I have so far.

```
package node;

public class IntNode {

    public int data;
    public IntNode next;
    public IntNode(int data, IntNode next) {
        this.data = data; this.next = next;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return data + "";
    }


    public static IntNode addBefore(IntNode front, int target, int newItem) {
        IntNode ptr = front;
        while(ptr != null)
        {

            if(ptr.data == target)
            {
                IntNode temp = new IntNode(newItem, ptr.next);
                ptr.next = temp;
            }
            ptr = ptr.next;
        }
        return front;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntNode L = null; //handle for the beginning of the LL
        L = new IntNode(19, null);
        IntNode temp = new IntNode(17, L);
        L = temp;
        addBefore(L, 17, 20);
        traverse(L);
    }

        public static void traverse(IntNode front){
            IntNode ptr = front; //ptr points to the first node of the LL

            while(ptr != null){
                System.out.print(ptr.data + " -> ");
                ptr = ptr.next;

        }  
        System.out.println("//");
        }
    }
```

Of course, instead of adding to before the target, the new node temp is being added after.  Is there any way to reverse the direction of the pointer so that it can be moved to point to the space before the target integer?

Comment: I've removed your [tag:javascript] question tag. Please understand that Java and JavaScript are two completely different languages, that questions tags and question titles are the most important parts of your question, and that if either are off, you won't get the correct experts to see your question. Just FYI.

Comment: 1) Keep a pointer `previous` that is always one step behind `ptr`; 2) make sure you handle the case where the first element of the list has the target, because this requires special handling.

Comment: You should remove the `static` modifier from `addBefore()`. You can then also remove `IntNode front` from the parameter list. You then call something like `L.addBefore(17, 20)`. You will also need to make some changes to `addBefore()`. You should study more about Object Orient programming in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Use a second pointer, let's say it's `prev`, to point to the node before `ptr` so that once you find the target node, you can add the new node after `prev` with the new node's `next` field pointing to `ptr`. However, a special case you have to watch for is if the target is the head of the list. In this case, you have to make the new node is the new head of the list. Here's what it should look like,

```
public static IntNode addBefore(IntNode front, int target, int newItem) {
    IntNode prev = null;
    IntNode ptr = front;
    while(ptr != null)
    {
        if(ptr.data == target)
        {
            if(prev == null)
            {
                front = new IntNode(newItem, front);
            }
            else
            {
                prev.next = new IntNode(newItem, ptr);
            }
            break;
        }
        prev = ptr;
        ptr = ptr.next;
    }

    return front;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about modifying the current node's data?

```
public static IntNode addBefore(IntNode front, int target, int newItem) {
    if (front.data == target) {
        IntNode currentFront = new IntNode(front.data, front.next);
        front.data = newItem;
        front.next = currentFront;
    } else {
        return addBefore(front.next, target, newItem);
    }
    return front;
}
```

Your:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    IntNode L = null; //handle for the beginning of the LL
    L = new IntNode(19, null);
    IntNode temp = new IntNode(17, L);
    L = temp;
    traverse(L);
    addBefore(L, 17, 20);
    traverse(L);
}
```

gave me:

```
17 -> 19 -> //
20 -> 17 -> 19 -> //
```

Another try:

```
traverse(L);
addBefore(L, 19, 20);
traverse(L);
```

gives:

```
17 -> 19 -> //
17 -> 20 -> 19 -> //
```